# android - add done to default android keyboard in portrait mode

Tags: android, keyboard

I need to add done button in my keyboard

my tries I add

> android:imeOptions="actionDone"
>               android:imeActionLabel="DONE"
>   to my Edittext

```
<EditText
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:id="@+id/passwordtext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:imeActionLabel="DONE"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/password"
             />
```

but I get done in landscape mode only , how can I have done inside off Enter 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the keyboard displays is completely up to the keyboard (which is its own app).  It may decide to honor your request, it may not.  There is no way to force it-  you've done as much as you can to ask it to do so.

Comment: so you saying I should make my own keyboard to approach that

Comment: That's the only way to 100 percent assure that it shows done. I wouldn't suggest it though- that's a lot of work to make even a creepy one, and people really like their third party keyboard

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
android:singleLine="true"
```

Comment: this work with large screens , not my htc one , but thank you

Answer (score 0):

I find answer thanks @Gabe I need to design my own keyboard

but I can change function of Enter button to Done 
If I add this code to my Edittext

```
 android:singleLine="true"
```

Comment: Two comments on that approach.  1 is that it will prevent the user from being able to enter multiple lines.  That may be ok for this field, it may not.  The second is that it isn't garanteed to work across all keyboards.